# What will be the most optimized position of a node in a binary tree with given specifications?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, tree

Suppose I have a binary tree in which a node can have either 0,1 or 2 children. A cost value is associated with each node, and it can be {5,10,20,40}. The most optimal placement of a new node is under a node with same or lower cost value. For example- a new node with cost value 20 is best placed under a node with cost value 20, but can also be placed under nodes with cost values 5 and 10.

Primary requirement of this algorithm is to complete the left and right child of a node if it is required, i.e. if a node with cost value 10 has a left child with cost value 10, then a new node having cost value 10 will be made the right child of the above node . The secondary requirement is to maximize the overall depth of the tree.

The tree cannot be rearranged at any point of time. If an incoming node is of lesser value, then there is no penalty involved.
Given the above requirements, how can we decide the best position of an incoming new node in the tree ? Can we write a general algorithm for it ?

Initially, I thought to complete each level of the tree first, but I don't think it would be optimal.

Comment: Unclear/incomplete description of the problem E.g what happens if the very first node to be processed is 40 and the next to arrive is 5? Is there a penalty? Or are you allowed to "dismantle" the tree and rearrange it? If the latter, are there any requirements on the time complexity?

Comment: added some details as requested

Answer (score 0):

> The secondary requirement is to *maximize* the overall depth of the tree.

That's a bit unusual.

The quickest way:

1. sort your input values
2. fill all the minimal value nodes (5's) in respect with the first requirement (still unclear if both left-right nodes must be filled in before going down a level. If it *must* then the max depth will be log2(N<sub>5</sub>) If "going deep on left" is allowed without filling in the right, then the max depth tree will degenerate in list with all right nodes to null).
   Call this the master tree
3. make a tree from the next values (say 10-value nodes) and attach this tree to the deepest branch of the master tree
4. repeat step 3 as necessary

Note: this is the simplest concept, the implementation may take advantage from the fact the master tree is sorted at all time and get over with the initial sort.